# Simple way of returning the length of the string to output

Tags: c++, string

I am writing a program that prints out a user-entered string and its length.
I was able to get this part:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
     string x;
     getline(cin, x);
     cout << "You entered: " << x << "String length/size is: "<<  /*  What comes Here ? */  <<endl;
 }
```

Rest of the process remains incomprehensible.

Comment: Have you checked the [reference material](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: Yes I have and it is incomprehesible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function that belongs to the string object, in your case `x.length()` will return the length of the string.

Comment: Another option is `x.size()`

Comment: Thank you George for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "You entered: " << x << "String lenght/size is: "<< x.size() << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`string.length()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) member function  or the [`string.size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string x ;
    getline (cin, x) ;
    cout << "You entered: " << x << "String length/size is: "<< x.length()<<endl;
}
```

The function above returns a `size_t` with the size of the string.